# Error "tput No value for $TERM and no -T specified"

Tags: sh, tput

I have a shell script in server A and I have a shell script in server B.
My logic is written like shell script in A gets executed and it calls a shell script in server B and executes it.
I am able to get the desired result when A executes B, but getting an error also along with the result. Error Message:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

I am using the following lines for getting output in color;

```
  RED=`tput setaf 1`
  GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
  YELLOW=`tput setaf 3`
  BLUE=`tput setaf 6`
  BOLD=`tput bold`
  RESET=`tput sgr0`
```

These lines are available in the shell script in both A and B.
When I execute the shell script in B by logging into server B, the desired output comes along with the color.
When I call the shell script from A and execute it, I am getting desired result plus the error message which I mentioned above.

Can you help in this regard?

FYI, I checked `"echo $TERM"` and output is `'xterm'` in both the servers.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: How are you calling the remote script? `ssh serverB scriptB </dev/null | less` will call `scriptB` where indeed the standard output of the script is not tied to a terminal locally.

Comment: This is how Iam executing the script on Server B from Server A
ssh <Server B> /home/wasadmin/test.sh

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
# when $TERM is empty (non-interactive shell), then expand tput with '-T xterm-256color'
[[ ${TERM}=="" ]] && TPUTTERM='-T xterm-256color' \
                  || TPUTTERM=''

declare -r    RES='tput${TPUTTERM} sgr0'       REV='tput${TPUTTERM} rev'
declare -r    fRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 1'    bRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 1'
declare -r    fGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 2'    bGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 2'
...
echo ${fRD}" RED Message: ${REV} This message is RED REVERSE. "${RES}
echo ${fGN}" GREEN Message: ${REV} This message is GREEN REVERSE. "${RES}
...
```

---

This way it makes no sense if there's an interactive or a non-interactive shell - tput still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We supposed that the shell or environment setting are different in two servers, if possible, you can past output of next commands from the two servers.

```
ps
```

This command helps us understand what kind of shell we are using.

```
env
```

This command helps us know the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`$TERM` will be unset when you log in via a script. Bypass the color-coding in this scenario, or hard-code an option to `tput`. (I would strongly suggest the former.)

```
RED=; GREEN=; YELLOW=; BLUE=; BOLD=; RESET=; 
case ${TERM} in
  '') ;;
  *)
      RED=`tput setaf 1`
      GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
      YELLOW=`tput setaf 3`
      BLUE=`tput setaf 6`
      BOLD=`tput bold`
      RESET=`tput sgr0`;;
esac
```

Comment: I tried including the 'case' you suggested in Server A first , no luck

Comment: I then tried using this 'case' in both the scripts(server A and server B), no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix the issue successfully now.

```
ssh <Server B> "TERM=xterm" <script in ServerB>
```

The desired output came back to ServerA with colors.